# Cast and : from parent to child class

Tags: c++, casting

i have 2 class: hObject, Drawer. Drawer inherit from hObject.

with this code i retrive a particular object by id:

```
hObject * foundObj = hManager::getInstance()->getObject("drawer_id");
```

now i want to correctly cast foundObj from hObject to Drawer. with:

```
vector<int> points = ((DrawerWidget *)hObject)->getPoints();
```

i recive

> expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

and what about dynamic cast?

consideration: my skills has been halved till i began c++

Comment: Shouldn't it be `((DrawerWidget*)hObject)->getPoints();`?

Comment: Why is it suddenly called `DrawerWidget`? And what about `dynamic_cast<Drawer*>(foundObj)`? Did that not work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- you wrote `hObject` (the type name) when you meant `foundObj` (the object name)
- it's a pointer, so you need to cast to a pointer type (UPDATE: the question has been edited to fix that).

Fixing that, and also using a less dangerous C++-style cast, the following should work:

```
vector<int> points = (static_cast<DrawerWidget*>(foundObj))->getPoints();
```

> and what about dynamic cast?

If the base class is polymorphic (that is, has at least one virtual function), then that would be safer still - you can check at runtime that the cast is valid:

```
if (DrawerWidget * dw = dynamic_cast<DrawerWidget*>(foundObj)) {
    vector<int> points = dw->getPoints();
} else {
    // not a DrawerWidget
}
```

although if you find yourself doing that, I would have a think about the design: it might be more appropriate to redesign the base class to support what you want to do via virtual functions, or to ensure at compile time that the conversion is valid.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: He wasn't when I wrote the answer.

Comment: Alright. You got +1 anyway. Also I'd hesitate to _recommend_ `dynamic_cast`; virtual dispatch and proper interfaces is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed; I've added a note to that effect.

Comment: Pretty much bang on now, I'd say

Answer (score 3):

You accidentally wrote the pointer's type, not name:

```
vector<int> points = ((DrawerWidget *)hObject)->getPoints();
//                                    ^^^^^^^
```

You meant:

```
vector<int> points = ((DrawerWidget *)foundObj)->getPoints();
//                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Also, for great victory, prefer C++-style casts:

```
vector<int> points = (static_cast<DrawerWidget*>(foundObj))->getPoints();
```

Finally, if it's possible that `*foundObj` isn't *actually* a `DrawerWidget`, and if these types are polymorphic, consider *not* casting and relying on virtual dispatch instead.